# Android: Graphview updates in onResume but fails by invalidate() method

Tags: android, graph, android-view, invalidation

I am working on application in which one custom view is updated by some back-end logic. Custom view is updates finely in `onResume()` method but it can not update by `view.invalidate();`.
I want that view got update onclick of button.

Code snippet as follows :

```
public class ChartDemo extends Activity {
private IDemoChart mChart;

Button displayGraph, reloadGraph;
LinearLayout linearLayout;
View view;

Random randomData, randomBattery;
int data, battery;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mChart = new SalesStackedBarChart();

    reloadGraph = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reloadView);

    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    view = new View(ChartDemo.this);
    loadGraphWithValues();

    reloadGraph.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            view.invalidate();
            loadGraphWithValues();
            // view = mChart.execute(ChartDemo.this);
        }
    });

    linearLayout.addView(view);
}

public void loadGraphWithValues() {
    data = generateDataValue();
    battery = generateBatteryValue();

    ListData list = new ListData();
    list.setData(data, battery);

    SalesStackedBarChart.values.add(list);

    view = mChart.execute(ChartDemo.this);
}

public int generateBatteryValue() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    randomData = new Random();
    return randomData.nextInt(100) + 1;
}

public int generateDataValue() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    randomBattery = new Random();
    return randomBattery.nextInt(100) + 1;
}

public class ListData {
    double data;
    double battery;

    // getter and setter methods..
}

}
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

```
view.invalidate();
loadGraphWithValues();
```

These should probably be switched, since you first update your view then you tell it to redraw itself. Also, what is your `mChart`? Is something asynchronous?

Edit: I guess here:

```
view = mChart.execute(ChartDemo.this);
```

you are creating a new view but not actually attaching it to the layout. Try putting the view returned in place of the existing view in your layout.

Comment: thanks for replying. mChart is instance of Bargraph. and its execute() method returns graphical view (i.e. bar graph).

Comment: No, values are inserted into list but i cant show. When I restarting the application graph is updated.

Comment: I have added it already in this way `linearLayout.addView(view);`

Comment: Try putting that line in loadGraphWithValues() as last instruction.